# Ajax filter returns all posts associated with custom taxonomy

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

so I'm trying to make ajax filter for custom taxonomy I made, but no matter on which button of term I click all posts from that taxonomy are returned. I want to return posts only associated with that term. Here's the code from query in ajax function

```
  $termIds = [7,3,5,4,6];
  $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => [
       [
          'taxonomy' => 'acquisition',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $termIds,
          'operator' => 'IN'
       ],
    ]
 ]);
```

Comment: When registering the custom taxonomy did you connect it to the 'post' type? Could you please post your code that includes the call to `register_taxonomy()`?

Comment: @kofeigen went on and built everything again following this tutorial https://wpflames.com/ajax-filter-for-wordpress-custom-post-type-taxonomy/ and now everything is working... anyways thanks for reaching out :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. If the solution to the problem is worth posting, please post it as an answer.